# Anonymous FTP: Please login with user and pass

Tags: tcp, privacy

I'm reading [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1635) and just for exercise I am trying to connect to a FTP site. I'm trying to connect to ftp.freebsd.org via terminal. However as I've read in the RFC, an anonymous user is allowed to list files. But strangely if I use the ls command it asks me to login with user and pass:

```
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
```

If I try to login with the USER command it tells me this:

```
530 Sorry, only anonymous ftp allowed.
```

That sounds like contradictory to me. How do I get a non anonymous connection to that site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical implementation for anonymous FTP access is to log on with the username of `anonymous` and the password being your email address.

---

Here's the output of what I ran. If you can post the output if your terminal session that might help us a lot:

```
C:\Users\mark.henderson>ftp ftp.freebsd.org
Connected to ftp.freebsd.org.
220 beastie.tdk.net FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.
User (ftp.freebsd.org:(none)):
500 USER : command not understood.
Login failed.
ftp> ls
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
ftp> user anonymous
331 Guest login ok, send your email address as password.
Password:
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
```

Comment: If I try "user anonymous" I get the same error: "530 Sorry, only anonymous ftp allowed.".

Comment: What did you type for the password?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - see updated answer

Comment: Ok the problem is that I was typing "user anonymous" too early, when ftp wasn't accepting commands.